# Javascript show / hide on click multi ID

Tags: javascript, text, show-hide

Im work with this script :
I want to show/hide text on click, with a single id it works great ( add a fade animation will be great ) but I'm not able to add another ID .. someone could help me ?!

THANKS

```js
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
```

```css
/**/

#wrap {
      float:left;
   width:100%;
   margin-top:20px;
      max-width: 320px;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2; }
#wrap p{
 border-bottom:none;
 border-top:none; }
   
#wrap img{margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom:15px;}
   h1 {
      font-size: 200%; }

   /* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */
   .more {
      display: none;
     }
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
   background:#fff;
      color:#333;
      padding: 10px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
       }


   a.hideLink {}
   a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
    color:#E99473;
       }
```

```html
 <div id="wrap">
     
      <p> 
        <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt=""/> 
      
        <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
      </p>
      <div id="example" class="more">
         <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
         <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div id="wrap">
     
      <p> 
        <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt=""/> 
      
        <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
      </p>
      <div id="example" class="more">
         <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
         <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div id="wrap">
     
      <p> 
        <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt=""/> 
      
        <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
      </p>
      <div id="example" class="more">
         <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
         <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: ID's are unique, you can't use the same ID for multiple elements

Comment: thank you, if someone could show to me how can i solve it?! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to HTML specification an `id` property of the element must be unique. You either need to assign different ids to each of your elements, or target them by some less restrictive parameter, such as `class`.

```
<div id="wrap">

  <p> 
    <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt=""/> 

    <a href="#" id="example1-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example1');return false;">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
  </p>
  <div id="example1" class="more">
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="example1-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example1');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrap">

  <p> 
    <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt=""/> 

    <a href="#" id="example2-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example2');return false;">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
  </p>
  <div id="example2" class="more">
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="example2-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example2');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrap">

  <p> 
    <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt=""/> 

    <a href="#" id="example3-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example3');return false;">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
  </p>
  <div id="example3" class="more">
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="example3-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example3');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, you're probably better off using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). With it you can do all kinds of selectors and manipulations (including fade effects) and have more reliable and cleaner code.

Here's your code rewritten without any ids:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.showLink,.hideLink').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.wrap').find('.more').fadeToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
/**/

.wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 320px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.wrap p {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.wrap img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */

.more {
  display: none;
}

a.showLink,
a.hideLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a.hideLink {}

a.showLink:hover,
a.hideLink:hover {
  color: #E99473;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="#" class="showLink">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
  </p>
  <div class="more">
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="hideLink">Hide this content.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="#" class="showLink">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
  </p>
  <div class="more">
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="hideLink">Hide this content.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    <img src="http://riccardobernucci.com/riviera/images/thumbs/FFBB.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="#" class="showLink">+ INFORMAZIONI</a>
  </p>
  <div class="more">
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="hideLink">Hide this content.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much! martynasma

Answer (score 0):

id values should never be same. Maintain unique id values. Then

1. If you want to show/hide that particular element, with unique id values and respective function:showHide('uniqueIdVal') your existing script should work.
2. If you are trying to hide/show all the elements on a single click, then you can select all such elements by maintaining a dummy class - XYZ for the elements and finding the elements by document.getElementsByClassName("XYZ");